# python string formatting and dictionary element

Tags: python, string, dictionary, format

I have the following code:

```
d= {'q': 23 , 2:5 ,  3: 'w'}
d['q']    # this gives 23  
f'adf {d[2]}'     # this generates : adf 5  (As expected)
f'adf {d['q']}'     # this generates syntax error, I was expecting : adf 23
```

Any explanation of what I am missing?!

Comment: Use double-quotes to avoid having nested quotes: `f'adf {d["q"]}'`

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes around `q` are ending the string, so you get a syntax error. you could use double quotes instead:

```
f'adf {d["q"]}'
```